# Separating UI web app and backend java layer using REST

Tags: rest, web-applications, architecture, frameworks

I plan to build a web application and am yet to decide on the language/technology to use. I plan to make this application speak with a java process on a remote server via REST for getting data. The java process is essential a data access layer exposing REST APIs for the web application to consume. At this point I am not concerned about the web application. I plan to implement the java process to be able to serve HTTP Requests in a scalable way. These requests would be returned with a JSON string representing the data.

Could you please advise on what framework/technology would suit my design the best ? I looked at Jersey and it seems to be a possible solution. But I am not sure if that would scale and if I am missing anything which is better.

Comment: retag: RPC that makes use of JSON is not "JSON-RPC".

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard which is [JAX-RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS). [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is the reference implementaion of JAX-RS but there are other good implementations, too.

If you *really* want to use standards, use [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/) as the reference implementation of a [Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) server. There are alternatives, too.